# How to set null to Integer in function posgrest from C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, function, null

I am confused about the solution of passing the parameter null to integer type. Here is my code in my .Net project with angular. Thanks for your help.

```
if(data.searchRange != "") 
{
    m_npgDB.SetParams("p_searchRange", int.Parse(data.searchRange)); 
}
else
{
    m_npgDB.SetParams("p_searchRange", ""); 
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to simply pass `null`? If not, does it understand/allow `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: Column in db allow null. I has a condition in postgrest function like (p_searchRange is null or search_range = p_searchRange )

Comment: An integer type could be null in C#, but you aren't  passing null in the  else clause, your'e passing an empty string.

Comment: @jdoer1997 Integers are value types, so they *cannot* be `null`...

Comment: Hmm I try change type is numeric and use SetParamNumber is " ". And it worked !

Comment: @Rufus L What I should have said is you can have  nullable integer variables .

Comment: @jdoer1997 I understand your idea is change type to nullable like int?

Comment: @jdoer1997 the method setPrams in NpgDBManager lib from metadata. Can not change method. If you pass nullable in parameter. data is character like "null" string. not null value

Answer (score 1):

You just creating a parameter

```
if (int.TryParse(data.searchRange, out var range))
{
    m_npgDB.SetParams("p_searchRange", range); 
}
else
{
    m_npgDB.SetParams("p_searchRange", null); 
}
```

You should be able to use nullable integer

```
var value = int.TryParse(data.searchRange, out var range) ? range : default(int?);

m_npgDB.SetParams("p_searchRange", value);
```

Comment: (FYI, the explicit cast on `range` isn't required)

Comment: SetParams method is accept parameter 2 is string, int, bool,etc but not accept nullable.

Comment: You can change `SetParams` method to accept nullable int or make it generic. ADO.NET accepts different types of .NET parameters for sql queries.

Comment: the method setPrams in NpgDBManager lib from metadata. Can not change method. If you pass nullable in parameter. data is character like "null" string. not null value.

Comment: Then use some other method which accepts `int?` or use Npgsql directly to create command with parameters.